# Saving subsequent items in a list after comparing with another list

Tags: python

I have two lists -- one of them a list of strings and the other a nested list of strings. I want to save the next 5 items in the list of strings after the point of intersection between the two lists.

For example, here are two lists I have:

```
list1 = [['this', 'is', 'the', 'common', 'part'], ['this', 'is', 'another', 'commonality']]
list2 = ['this', 'is', 'the', 'common', 'part', 'and', 'i', 'am', 'saving', 'this', 'blah', 'blah', 'this', 'is', 'another', 'commonality', 'i', 'am', 'also', 'saving', 'this']
```

The desired output is:

```
result = [['and', 'i', 'am', 'saving', 'this'], ['i', 'am', 'also', 'saving', 'this']]
```

My code had many unfriendly nested conditionals -- would appreciate if anyone has a clean way to achieve the goal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try it like so:

```
amount_of_subsequent_items = 5
result = []
for sublist in list1:
    for i in range(len(list2)-1):
        if sublist == list2[i:i+len(sublist)]:
            result.append(list2[i+len(sublist):i+len(sublist)+amount_of_subsequent_items])
```

This iterates your `list1` by looking for an occurrence of a `sublist` (of `list1`) at any place in `list2`. If an occurrence was found, a list containing the next `amount_of_subsequent_items` subsequent items of `list2` will be stored in `result`.

Comment: While your code may work, there is some code smell with the magic numbers (-1, +5). You could also improve your answer by providing an explanation. ("The sublist breaks up the nested lists and treats each one separately," for example.)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I added an explanation for my code. I think the -1 is self explanatory since ranges (with only an end parameter) will always start with 0.

Comment: thank you so much! this was really helpful